# Android:connect with web services

Tags: android, web-services

I created page & web services. I assign to retrive value on button Click functionality. But the application not responding after clicked.

Comment: Share your code to call webservice and logcat error if any.

Comment: code + stacktrace pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use AsyncTask, see the link to how to use AsyncTask and how to get retrieve  the data 
[How to use httpget in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938420/how-to-use-httpget-in-my-app/17938774#17938774)

Answer (score 1):

Might be you are calling the webservice from ui thread which is largely discouraged and throws exception above gingerbread do it by using the AsyncTask class.

```
class nwthread extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>

{
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
//progress dialog invoke ( notifies the user about whats going on better than making them stare on a blank screen)
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //make request to webservice
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
//dismiss progress dialog
        // update the UI here ... ie declare adapters / bind them, update other views

    }
}
```

The above is an example of it!
execute this from within your onCreate() as

```
new nwthread.execute();
```